# Rails nested form for one to many to be shown only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, model-associations

I have got two models `Event` and `EventLocation` .`Event` has_many `EventLocations` .
I am using nested simple nested form for accepting `EventLocation` attributes in 'Event' form

I also have other view for conferences. the only difference between event and conferences is that events will have single event location where as a conference will have multiple event locations . so is there any way that I could show event_location form only once in **Event Views**. right now I am able to display event_location form in the following way

```
= f.simple_fields_for :event_locations do |event_location|
  = event_location.input :location
  %br
  = event_location.input :start_time
  %br
  = event_location.input :end_time
  %br
  = event_location.input :address
= f.link_to_add "Add Event Location".html_safe, :event_locations
```

but this gives me an option of adding multiple locations for event also ,which i don't want.

Comment: I think that `link_to_add` is a helper method, because it isn't peresent at api.rubyonrails.org. Can you publish thim method?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html 
I think that this link will help

model

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :avatar
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar, allow_destroy: true
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

accepts_nested_attributes_for(*attr_names)